# GUI for Windows Application

Tags: windows, user-interface

Currently I'm working on a Windows application & 
I was looking for a technology that gives me the freedom to build/customize the GUI widgets to build the most attractive GUI for windows application.

Like that of:

[Zune](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/Live/Partners/Zune)

[MetroTwit](http://www.metrotwit.com/)

[Hamstersoft Zip Archiver](http://www.hamstersoft.com/free-zip-archiver/)

[Blu](http://2010.thirteen23.com/experiences/desktop/blu/)

Win8/Win7/Vista (if possible also WinXP) are my target platforms where this application must/will/should be running.

Please suggest which one to use?
If possible the pros & cons for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I would try Qt. It is amazing and let's you customise it's looks with CSS
http://qt-project.org/
Has one of the best documentations around and an awesome community (helped me a lot when I was learning it a lot of months ago)

Edit: not 100% sure for the CSS part(if it is pure css or not), but you can design custom style sheets, which basically do the same thing.

Edit2: Qt works on C++, there is an implementation for Python as well, in what programming language do you want to build it ?